# Calculating the mean of a Cox regression using R

Tags: r, self-study, mean, survival, cox-model

I have been asked to calculate the mean survival time for each of the two groups (expensive and cheap glasses) based on this output as a review question.

I know that a cox regression is of the form $\lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \dots)$. To me this appears to be similar to an exponential distribution, where the mean is $1/\lambda$, so is the mean for this $\dfrac{\lambda_0(t)}{\beta_1x_1 + \dots}$? I have looked extensively online and have not found a clear way to calculate this. This seems like a very simple question, so I must be misunderstanding something fundamental about what Cox regression is actually doing.

My sample solution is here if people can point out where I may have gone wrong?

$\lambda (t)=\lambda_0(t)\exp(-0.9399x_1)$ for the expensive wine $\implies \mu_{\text{expensive}} = \lambda_0(t)\times(-0.9399)$

$\lambda (t) = \lambda_0(t)\exp(x_1)$ for the cheaper wine. $\implies \mu_{\text{expensive}} = \lambda_0(t)$.

Clearly this is wrong as one of the two functions would be negative and survival function can't be negative. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(parties, event) ~ cost, data = glasses2)
n= 20, number of events= 12
                coef exp(coef) se(coef) z Pr(>|z|)
costexpensive -0.9399 0.3907 0.6606 -1.423 0.155
               exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
costexpensive   0.3907     2.56        0.107   1.426

Concordance= 0.627 (se = 0.072 )
Likelihood ratio test= 2.08 on 1 df, p=0.1
Wald test = 2.02 on 1 df, p=0.2
Score (logrank) test = 2.16 on 1 df, p=0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest trying to make a connection with the exponential distribution, as that line-of-work won't lead anywhere. You'll have to go back to first principles to calculate the mean of the Cox model. The mean of a survival time, $T$, can be calculated using its survival function, $S(t)$:

$$
E[T] = \int_0^{\inf} S(t) dt
$$

What is $S(t)$ for the Cox model? It's the following:

$$S(t) = \exp \left( -\lambda_0(t) \exp(\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \dots) \right) $$

Can we compute the integral now? No, because $\lambda_0(t)$ is not specified (hence the *semi*-parametric label). Given a dataset, we can infer $\lambda_0(t)$, but it's not going to be smooth, nor analytical (i.e. not simple to integrate).

There's another complication with the mean survival time. If the survival function, $S(t)$, does not reach 0, then the integral above is infinite. And often with the Cox model, we don't observe subjects long enough to see $S(t)$ go to 0. This is solved by using another summary statistic, like the *median survival time*, or the *restricted-mean-survival-time*, defined:

$$
RMST(\tau) = \int_0^{\tau} S(t) dt
$$

Comment: I had no idea that was the survival function for the Cox model that's very helpful! I still don't understand how to take the integral of this function because $\lambda_0(t)$ is not defined. I can see that $\beta_1=-0.9399$, but I still do not understand how to go from that to finding the mean of the function. Is there something in the output from the cox regression that would help me continue on to integrate this?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: you can't take the integral without numerical software. Normally, users of the Cox model don't report mean lifetimes, but hazard ratios only. Why are you interested in the mean? Knowing that may provide another solution to your problem.

Comment: Ah, I see thank you. As I said at the beginning of my question this is a review question set before my medical stats exam. Apparently I should be able to calculate the mean for both the expensive glass group and cheap glass group, from the cox regression output. Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem right. Are you sure you are suppose to use the Cox model? Can you provide exactly what the question is asking?

Comment: "Cox Proportional Hazards modelling

Data from 10 more expensive glasses are available, and the output from a Cox proportional hazards model including the type of glass as a two-level covariate is presented below:"

"What is the mean survival time of the cheaper glasses?"

"What is the mean survival time of the more expensive glasses?." The provided information is in my original question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think you can solve this...

Comment: Turns out you were right! I missed the very beginning of the paper, where it said "solve or state that it is not possible." So so sorry for the trouble, but you did give me much more understanding so thank you!

Comment: hahaha phew! I was questioning my own understanding!

Answer (score 2):

In R you can use the `rms` package's `cph` function which is a front-end for `survival::coxph`.  Then you can apply the `rms` `Mean` function to the fit object to create an R function that computes RMST from the fit object.  You can use this created function to transform axes of various graphs including nomograms and partial effect plots, as detailed in [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).